# Python for loop and UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, for-loop, local, insertion-sort, xrange

I am a python new comer. Right Now I am having some troubles with python's local variable setting.

Here is the thing, I got a mistake output called :

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i1' referenced before assignment
```

By searching on the StackOverFlow, I now know that my fault was due to the functioning range of the local variable. For python is a dynamic language and doesn't have variable declaration. Is there anyone outer there who can help to fix that? I really need to use this variable after the iteration. Thanks  a lot.(Although I know it can works, I prefer not to use the global declaration)

Here is my code, I use it as to fulfill the insertion sort.

```
def insert_sort(my_str):
    locf = len(my_str)
    for j1 in xrange(1,locf,1):
        ticket = 0
        temp = my_str[j1]
        for i1 in xrange(j1-1,0,-1):
            if i1>=0 and my_str[i1]<my_str[j1]:
                ticket  = 1
                my_str[i1+1] = my_str[i1]
            else:
                break
        if ticket == 0:
            my_str[i1] = temp
    return my_str
```

The mistake is :

```
  File "/Users/tk/PycharmProjects/pyal/Insertation Sort.py", line 34, in <module>
    print insert_sort(tk_list)
  File "/Users/tk/PycharmProjects/pyal/Insertation Sort.py", line 15, in insert_sort
    my_str[i1] = temp
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i1' referenced before assignment
```

I know it is because **i1** is within the **for loop** and cannot be used outsides. But what if I do need to do so? Is there any compensate methods?

Sure, I do can not to use the for loop and use while instead. But sometimes I do need to use a local variable within a loop outside its range. 
And I have already wrote it out using the while loop:

```
def insert_sort(my_str):
    locf = len(my_str)
    for j1 in xrange(1,locf,1):
        temp = my_str[j1]
        i1 = j1 -1
        while i1>=0 and my_str[i1]>temp:
            my_str[i1+1] = my_str[i1]
            i1 -= 1
        my_str[i1+1] = temp
    return my_str
```

Thanks you sincerely.

Comment: But by using the `i1` outside the loop, you are using its last value right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you *can* use values assigned in a `for` loop definition outside that loop, e.g.:

```
for x in range(5):
    print x # 0 1 2 3 4
print x # still 4
```

In your code, however, when `j1 == 1`, (its first value) `xrange(j1 - 1, 0, -1)` is `xrange(0, 0, -1)`, which is an empty iterator, so `i1` is *never assigned*.

The minimal fix is to change how `j1` is assigned:

```
for j1 in xrange(2, locf, 1):
```

Now `i1` will get assigned for all values of `j1`.

Comment: Wow, Now I got it... But what about the functioning range of this variable. Now I just got a little bit of confused...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "functioning range". *Which* variable?

Comment: In you case is the x. When and where will it not working anymore... Will this variable keep alive all the way until the function itself is end?

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, that will remain in scope until the function ends, retaining the last value it had in the loop (unless reassigned).

Comment: @Tk_75963 that's a sketchy-looking link; I'll take your word for it!

Comment: Ah, It is my personal blog. Right now I am trying to using python to fulfill every pseudocode in a book called 'Introduction to The Design and Analysis of Algorithm'. I registered the domain myself, so it looks not so nice. Sorry for the late reply...